# How to properly handle this read timeout error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout

So I'm using this python package `lyricsgenius` to scrape lyrics from website genius.com using the website's API. In this script, I want it to scrape 300 songs of Drake:

```
import lyricsgenius

genius = lyricsgenius.Genius(API_KEY)
artist = genius.search_artist("Drake", max_songs=300, sort="title")
```

However, it stopped at song 106 and displayed the error message:

```
Song 106: "Draft Day"
"Drake & DJ Semtex Interview" is not valid. Skipping.
Timeout raised and caught:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.genius.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-575a1d98f954> in <module>
      1 genius = lyricsgenius.Genius(API_KEY)
----> 2 artist = genius.search_artist("Drake", max_songs=300, sort="title")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lyricsgenius/api.py in search_artist(self, artist_name, max_songs, sort, per_page, get_full_info, allow_name_change, artist_id)
    329                 else:
    330                     info = {'song': song_info}
--> 331                 song = Song(info, lyrics)
    332 
    333                 # Attempt to add the Song to the Artist

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lyricsgenius/song.py in __init__(self, json_dict, lyrics)
     24             save_lyrics: Save the song lyrics to a JSON or TXT file.
     25         """
---> 26         self._body = json_dict['song'] if 'song' in json_dict else json_dict
     27         self._body['lyrics'] = lyrics
     28         self._url = self._body['url']

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

How do I set up so that it will stop scraping when it reaches 300 songs?

Comment: it seems it gets `None` in `json_dict` and it can't do `None['song']` - maybe server has restrictions or bug and it can't send it. Ask author of script and admins of genius.com

Comment: Try providing the argument `retries=3` (or any other number, default is 1) in the constructor; that solved it for me. I also passed `per_page=50` to the `search_artist()` function, idk if that helped too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Realize this is an issue within the `lyricsgenius` package being used (even if there is an internal failure, it should report that properly).
2. Check if it works with the most recent release of the package. What is your `lyricsgenius.__version__`? Most recent seems to be 1.6.0 which was only created 3 days ago. Try to install it manually (`pip install lyricsgenius`).
3. If the problem persists, look up the official repository for contact details. The [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/project/lyricsgenius/) sends you to https://github.com/johnwmillr/LyricsGenius/issues. The project's README says to "just open an issue".